# Use CREATE USER in Postgres by passing password in variable

Tags: postgresql

I have the following function in PostgreSQL:

```
create function test_createuser(username varchar, userpassword varchar) returns void as $$
begin
  CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD userpassword;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

However this gives the following error:

```
syntax error at or near "userpassword"
```

The function compiles if I place instead a literal string as the password, such as 'mypassword'.

Is there a way to call create user and pass the password from a variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to use dynamic SQL:

```
EXECUTE format('CREATE USER %I PASSWORD %L', username, userpassword);
```

Comment: this line is subject to SQL injections and I should address that, is that correct?

Comment: This line is *not* vulnerable to SQL injection. It's good that you think about these things though! `%I` and `%L` will escape everything properly.

Answer (score 3):

I still got the same parse error using the EXECUTE method (ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2" - Note: the password starts with a "2").
Instead I added string quotation marks when I read the password from the environment variable.

```
\set psqluser `echo "$PSQL_USER"`
\set psqlpassword `echo "'$PSQL_PASSWORD'"`    -- Add the quotations '' for the password already here
CREATE USER :psqluser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD :psqlpassword;
```

I don't know if it is good practice, but it works.